# Align table content at different symbols

Tags: tables

I want to align my table content at different symbols, e. g. `=` and `\leq`.
Is this, how one would to it, or is there an easier way?

Btw is there a difference between `r@{$\;$}l` and `r@{ }l`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{title}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{r@{$\;$}l}
\toprule
  $0$ & $\leq 111$\\
\midrule
$111$ & $= 100 + 11$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: { } is 3.3333pt wide.  {$\;$} is 2.77771pt wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define suitable column types that mimic what `align` does.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\caption{title}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}r<{$} @{} >{${}}l<{$}}
\toprule
  0   &\leq 111 \\
\midrule
  111 &= 100 + 11 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it matter, whether I write `111 &= 100` or `111 & = 100`?

Comment: @Ben No, because they're typeset in math mode where spaces are ignored anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array instead of tabular and do everything in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]% [h!] is just embarassing
\caption{title}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
$\begin{array}{r@{\;}l}
\toprule
  0 & \leq 111\\
\midrule
111 & = 100 + 11\\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

The *correct* way to do it is

```
$\begin{array}{r@{}l}
\toprule
  0 &\null\leq 111\\
\midrule
111 &\null= 100 + 11\\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
```

but I wouldn't say it is easier.

Comment: `\null` is an undocumented command; use `{}` instead.